# How to disable Yahoo! Mail account key

Tags: yahoo-mail

I want to revert to just using my password again.

How can I turn off the account key login with My Yahoo that requires a code to be sent to a phone?

If not, send it to my Gmail address?

I've tried turning it off but when I go to Security in Account Management I get caught in an infinite loop. When I click on Manage, it asks me to login with a code sent to my phone. When I do and click on Manage again, it goes back to sending me another text to login again, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to see the disable button. I wonder why Yahoo chose to keep it all the way down and hardly visible. Follow these steps and you will be free too because just like you, I dislike the account key sign in. So if my phone is not around I can't log into my email?

Steps

- Once logged into your email, click on account info, like where you go to sign out
- Click Account security.
- Click Manage next to Yahoo Account Key.
- Look to the bottom and click Disable Account Key, mind you, it will look as if it is not populated but it is.
- Click Yes, disable Account Key to confirm.
- Click Got it.